# How to use hexo server --draft and Livereload

Tags: livereload, hexo

I am writing draft blog posts using hexo. I am running the hexo server as follows:

```
hexo server --draft
```

This watches for changes in the draft folder and generates the draft posts which can be viewed at http://0.0.0.0:4000

The problem is I can't work out how to use [live-reload](http://livereload.com) while writing drafts.

With livereload I call

```
live-reload --port 9091 public/
```

And use use the javascript implementation with the browser

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//localhost:9091"></script>
```

I can see why this doesn't work, live-reload is looking for changes to the public folder. With the server running in draft mode, I don't know what folder the html generated drafts are being stored in. I've searched my project structure and can't seem to see anything obvious. Any ideas?

Comment: @gaz-edge , please see my new post, http://stackoverflow.com/a/40865769/304330 (below) - it address Hexo-native browser reload plugins ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hexo **can** offer [live-reload](http://livereload.com/)-like functionality via the'[Browsersync-based](https://www.browsersync.io)' plugin, '[hexo-browsersync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hexo-browsersync)'.

There is actually also a [hexo-livereload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hexo-livereload) plugin, but the net, and [hexo-browsersync's NPMJS rating](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hexo-browsersync), seem to favour the [Browsersync Hexo plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hexo-browsersync).

Christopher Martin's blog post '[Getting Started with the Hexo Blogging Framework](https://www.cgmartin.com/2016/01/03/getting-started-with-hexo-blog/)', outlines the plugin's installation and usage, as well as many other helpful tips:

> To install the hexo-browsersync plugin:
>
> $ npm install hexo-browsersync --save
> $ hexo server --draft --open  #restart the server

This might possibly suit the OP's original question better than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I normally do this sort of thing:

```
hexo generate --draft --watch & live-server --port=4000 public
```

This generates the site in the `public` folder and watches for changes, whilst also serving said `public` folder with auto-updates.

Not exactly answering the specific question but maybe someone will find it useful.

**Note: You will need to have `live-server` and `hexo-cli` installed globally, or locally if running via npm scripts.**

Answer (score 1):

hexo server serves the source version of the post not the public version. If you set livereload to watch the source folder livereload will work. I suggest setting livereload to use a 1 second or so delay before processing so the on the fly source generation to occur before reload is attempted.

Answer (score 0):

Looking to the `--draft` option implementation at [Github](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/pull/340/files) shows that it only extends the `post` processor to the `_draft` folder. So the place where it puts draft rendered files is the same it puts published posts.

However, `hexo server` does not save published posts in `public` directory as might be suggested by the question; `public` directory is populated by `hexo generate` command only. In fact hexo server does not save temporary files as it renders them on the fly.

I think [live-reload](http://livereload.com) will not work this way.